# "‘sockaddr_in’ undeclared (first use in this function)" error despite including the requisite headers

Tags: c, sockets, header-files

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>#include <net/if.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define BACKLOG 10

void * get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa){
    if(sa->sa_family == AF_INET){
            return &((sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_addr;
    }
    else if(sa->sa_family == AF_INET6){
            return &((sockaddr_in6 *)sa)->sin6_addr;
    }
}
```

I am using the sockaddr_in struct in my code to chekc whether an incoming connection is an IPv4 or an IPV6 address. I get the error "‘sockaddr_in’ undeclared (first use in this function)" here despite including the netinet/in.h header in my code. Is there something that I am not seeing here?

Comment: Which platform and compiler?

Comment: I ran it on ubuntu with GCC. Sorry I missed mentioning that.

Comment: I wonder what you try to accomplish. The distiction between v4 and v6 which you do in the function must be done again on using the return value. So it might be better to put the code above there as well. Maybe it would be better to use [`getnameinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getnameinfo.html)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sockaddr_in`  is not `typedef`, so try using it with `struct` like following

```
(struct sockaddr_in *)
```