# C casting sockaddr into sockaddr_in

Tags: c, sockets, casting

for some reasons my pointer needs to point sockaddr not sockaddr_in , how can i cast these two structures in order to use sin_family , sin_pot and sin_addr with the sockaddr pointer ?
here 's my code

```
static int proxy_getaddr(char *HostName, int Port, SockAddrType *Result)
      .......

Result->sin_family=AF_INET;
Result->sin_port=htons((unsigned short)Port);
     ........

memcpy((char*)&Result->sin_addr,(char*)Host->h_addr,sizeof(Result->sin_addr));
```

As you may see the pointer i need to cast is result here and my console error is

```
 ‘const struct sockaddr’ has no member named ‘sin_family’
 ‘const struct sockaddr’ has no member named ‘sin_port’
‘const struct sockaddr’ has no member named ‘sin_addr’
```

Comment: First of all, are you 100% sure that `Result` is a `sockaddr_in` pointer? Other than that, what have you tried for typecasting?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg indeed, would like to see the declaration of `SockAddrType`.

Comment: #define SockAddrType const struct sockaddr , Result is a sockaddr pointer and i want it to be a sockaddr_in pointer

Comment: What I wonder is, how can you be sure that the caller is calling your function with a `sockaddr_in` pointer? What if it's `sockaddr_in6` or `sockaddr_un` or some other socket address variant? There's a reason the standard socket functions have a parameter for the structure type (or size for the older functions).

Comment: great i was about to post similar [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606386/sockaddr-in-undeclared-first-use-in-this-function-error-despite-including/16606558#16606558)

Comment: no actually that didn't fix it i was wrong i am sure that the pointer is a sockaddr_in because that's what it used to be before i change it into sockaddr because i also use it for a bind call that needs a sockaddr pointer

Comment: Then why not just simply cast it? If you don't want to cast it every time you use it, just make a local `sockaddr_in` pointer and use that.